# float to String conversion in c++

Tags: c++, microprocessors

I am programming on a LPC 1769 microprocessor, but I am unable to figure out how to convert a floating point number into a string so that I could print it on my Display . I am using the `sprintf` command but still my program is showing a memory error.  How do I convert a `float` into a string?  I need to do this without using the standard library.

Comment: *"Please Provide me a code that convert a float into a string."*, you need to read this: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @JohnnyGraber ?Honestly he probably hasnt tried anything but he is saying sprint command, maybe he means sprintf, which means he is trying to do this: `sprintf(charstar, "%f", floatvalue)`

Comment: First check if your microprocessor & the compiler supports float. Many processor don't.

Comment: The problem is likely that sprintf doesn't actually display anything on the display. He might need to figure out how to print something on whatever is the display device

Comment: OK, first, can you successfully sprintf() simpler stuff to the output - a literal string, for example?  If so, then ensure that the floating-point support for printf/sprintf is enabled in your build configuration, (as hinted at by @naishsane).  If so, can you sprintf an FP value that is not returned by your A->D driver?  You have to split this problem up to effectively debug it.

Answer (score 3):

This will work also:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUM_TEXT_SIZE 64U
float value = 3.14159f;
char text_array[MAXIMUM_TEXT_SIZE];
snprintf(text_array, MAXIMUM_TEXT_SIZE, "%4.2f", value);
```

The string form of the floating point value will be in `text_array`.

Before using `std::string` on an embedded system with constrained memory, verify that you have a decent memory allocation and garbage recovery set up.  If not, use an *allocator* for the string to allocated from a fixed size memory pool.  Search SO for "fragmentation".

Comment: Please, you seem to be on SO long enough to know the things about a decent answer. Code only is bad, explain.. (Yes, even such short ones. Why e.g. do you choose 64 as array size? why do you use `%4.2f`? )

Comment: @stefan:  The OP did not give any requirements for formatting the floating point, only that it be output.  This is a standard method in embedded systems, that I have been programming for over 40 years.  The text array is 64 because that is a nice power of 2 (for alignment purposes) and also because the OP did not give the length of the string.  Also, I am using `snprintf` because that is safer than `sprintf`.  Did you know that C code will also compile under C++?  What makes this a bad answer?

Comment: @stefan: The "%4.2f" is a *format specifier* that says to print the floating point value in a field that is 4 characters wide (including the decimal point) with 2 digits of precision.  The text should come out to "3.14".

Comment: You don't need to explain it to me, I do know about this stuff. It is supposed to be a part of the answer. It's better now, but `%4.2f` still seems to be an odd choice.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you can use [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert a numerical value to an `std::string`, which you can turn into a C-style string with the `c_str()` method.

Comment: actually i want a code that does not include any standard lib. function or any other lib .  includes

Answer (score 2):

This code will do that for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    float val =3.456;
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << val;
    std::string test = stream.str();
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

test will contain the float from `val` as in 3.456.

What it looks like you are trying to do is use `sprintf`, in which case you can do this:

```
char buffer[40]
float val =3.456;

sprintf(buffer, "%f", val);
std::string out(buffer);
std::cout << out << std::endl;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Be aware that mixing C I/O and C++ I/O methods may be problematic.  See `std::ios::width` and `std::ios::precision` for formatting using C++ I/O manipulators.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the advice, I thought i was providing a c method and a c++ method individually, but you are correct, i am outputting to std::cout using c++ methods.